# Google Sheets - Conditional formatting based on multiple cells in a row

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make conditional formatting in Google Sheets.
Idea is to change colour (better to change also a value) of cells in `J2:J1000` depending on other cells in a row. 
So, e.g. J2 should change its value (or just a colour) to 'Ok' (green) when values in E2:I2 are 'Ok' OR 'Not Relevant'

I'm trying something like `=OR(($E:$I='Ok'),($E:$I='Not Relevant'))`
But all my attempts are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## paste this in **J2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((E2:E="ok")+(E2:E="not relevant"))*
                 ((F2:F="ok")+(F2:F="not relevant"))*
                 ((G2:G="ok")+(G2:G="not relevant"))*
                 ((H2:H="ok")+(H2:H="not relevant"))*
                 ((I2:I="ok")+(I2:I="not relevant")); "Ok"; ))
```

## and then paste this in conditional formatting as a custom formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((E2:E="ok")+(E2:E="not relevant"))*
                 ((F2:F="ok")+(F2:F="not relevant"))*
                 ((G2:G="ok")+(G2:G="not relevant"))*
                 ((H2:H="ok")+(H2:H="not relevant"))*
                 ((I2:I="ok")+(I2:I="not relevant")), 1, ))
```

[image: 0]

## [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1STarPBaTpdHLzG2K0ziIsDgXSFzjSjebY7EfplDaqog/edit#gid=0)

---

if the conditional formatting is still not working try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(((E2:E="ok")+(E2:E="not relevant"))*
                 ((F2:F="ok")+(F2:F="not relevant"))*
                 ((G2:G="ok")+(G2:G="not relevant"))*
                 ((H2:H="ok")+(H2:H="not relevant"))*
                 ((I2:I="ok")+(I2:I="not relevant")); 1; ))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need *all* of the cells to be either OK or Not relevant, you need

```
=countif(E2:I2,"OK")+countif(E2:I2,"Not relevant")=columns(E2:I2)
```

If you need *any* of the cells to be OK or Not relevant, you need just the first part

```
=countif(E2:I2,"OK")+countif(E2:I2,"Not relevant")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, i need all of the cells to be either ok or not relevant.

However, none of formulas work. I always get formula parse error.

Maybe i'm doing something wrong

Comment: OK, I've added a screenshot, see if that helps.

Comment: It could also be to do with your locale, you may need to change , to ;

Comment: It was because of a locale. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Enter this Conditional Formatting Custom Formula in J2

```
=and(OR($E2="Ok",$E2="Not Relevant"),OR($F2="Ok",$F2="Not Relevant"),OR($G2="Ok",$G2="Not Relevant"),OR($H2="Ok",$H2="Not Relevant"),OR($I2="Ok",$I2="Not Relevant"))
```

Apply to J2:J1000

Comment: So it doesn't support range. Each column has to be in the condition.

However, it doesn't work for J2. Gives 'Formula parse error'.

But thanks anyway

Comment: Here is my test spreadsheet. Make a copy. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rIHi_049tcWidU9V5PLKhoguBN6i7OV16dJ493cyLpQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=OR(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(--(E2:I2={"Ok"}))), ARRAYFORMULA(--(E2:I2={"Not Relevant"})))
```

It will take the values from E2:I2, if they are either "Ok" or "Not Relevant" the result will be TRUE

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(
  E2:E="OK","ok",E2:E="not relevant","ok",
  F2:F="OK","ok",F2:F="not relevant","ok",
  G2:G="OK","ok",H2:H="not relevant","ok",
  H2:H="OK","ok",H2:H="not relevant","ok",
  I2:I="OK","ok",I2:I="not relevant","ok"
)))
```

[image: Result including conditional formatting]